What is the difference between Assistant and User language model chat messages?
VS Code's extension API documentation for LanguageModelChatMessage mentions two types of messages- namely Assistant and User. What is the difference between the two? I am trying to create a participant and would like to understand the features available.
Here is the best documentation I could find here but I still could not understand the difference between them: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/language-model#build-the-language-model-prompt.
